# Как подключить компьютер к домофонной линии?

Tags: аудио, электроника, схемотехника

Как согласовать аудиовход и аудиовыход в двухпроводную линию? Какую придумать схему для включения в разрыв линии?

Упрощенная схема устройств с обеих сторон:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При опущенной аналоговой трубке (микрофон шунтируется; в линии 50 Ом от динамика). Нужно ёе отключать, чтоб поднять компьютерную.

Comment: это для проверки, как скоро закроют?

Comment: По какой причине?) Вопросы по компьютерной переферии офтоп?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, большая половина вопросов на ruSO — по сути офтопик. Так что не закроют :)

Answer (score 4):

Есть два варианта - через разделительные трансформаторы, что дорого и надежно,
или через разделительные конденсаторы.

Но если при втором варианте как-то в линию домофона попадет 220 или 380 вольт - сгорит все.

Также нужно понимать, что в грозу на длинных линиях домофона могут навестись киловольты.

Comment: Больше 12 вольт там не бывает. 6 вольт переменка  при вызове, 2 вольта переменка при разговоре.

Comment: Развязка с линией не проблема. Вопрос : как "скрутить" вход и выход на компьютере? Микшер на 3 резисторах звездой?

Comment: Линейный выход через конденсаторы на место микрофона, линейный вход через конденсаторы - на место динамика.

Comment: Можно обойтись без транзистора? Линейный выход достаточно усилен как мне х.???? Бю..

Comment: Транзистор лучше оставить, он нужен для согласования сопротивления линии.

Comment: >Больше 12 вольт там не бывает

Я это сообщение воспринимаю как добровольный отказ от того, чтобы сделать безопасное устройство. Дальнейшие советы по поводу безопасности конструкции я давать отказываюсь.

Comment: В устройствах уже включенных в линию нет трансформаторов. Транзистор там для усиления микрофона.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127636/discussion-between-gbg-and-eri).

Comment: Третий вариант: через разделительные оптроны.